# Vehicle misfuel

Tags: engine, diesel, gasoline, peugeot

I used a 2015 Peugeot Boxer Luton van  ( 154K mileage ). It had a full tank of diesel to start and I travelled 300 miles , used roughly half a tank ,and then it broke down , there is a suggestion it was misfuelled. Which is not true . Is it possible for the vehicle to travel such a distance if there is a small amount of petrol in the diesel tank?

Comment: More likely to be crud in the diesel that clogged the fuel filter.

Comment: It would help if we knew what the failure was. Gasoline in diesel is going to do two things: not combust well and lower the fuel lubricity. If the failure was lubrication-related (engine bearings, cylinder walls) or fuel-system related (HP fuel pump, injectors), then yes it could be implicated. If the failure was the fan belt snapped or the computer died, then it would be no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, definitely, if "a small amount" is in the neighborhood of 10-15%. But I don't think this would be the cause of a breakdown.

The gas stations in my area (northern USA) used to switch to a "winter blend" diesel in the winter which contained 10-15% gasoline, with the higher percentage used only in colder regions. The added gasoline was intended to prevent gelling of the diesel fuel. They were doing this at least into the 1990s. Today the refineries use other additives in winter to prevent gelling.

The point is, everyone driving a diesel vehicle, including me, used this fuel exclusively in winter and did not consider it to be misfueling. It caused no harm that I am aware of.

**ADDENDUM**

Although user71659 claims in comments that gasoline in winter diesel is a myth, it was indeed used in Europe and the USA into the 1990s as other online sources attest. In that era, it caused no harm, as demonstrated by the many cars and trucks that logged hundreds of thousands of miles / kilometers on the same diesel engine.

However, winterizing diesel fuel with gasoline is not presently the industry practice and is not presently recommended by diesel engine manufacturers since in today's cars gasoline as a diesel additive *can* cause damage. Whether a single tank with a small quantity of gasoline mixed in can result in engine failure is an open question. I personally don't believe it for a moment.

Comment: Myth. They don't blend gasoline into winterized diesel fuel. They blend kerosene, a.k.a. #1 Diesel, a.k.a Jet A.

Comment: @user71659 You know what they say about opinions. You may have missed ***used to*** in the first paragraph. I was there -- northern USA -- in the 1990s and you were not, or you would have smelled the gasoline fumes coming out of the diesel fuel filler in winter. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter_diesel_fuel#Blending for a history lesson.

Comment: The very first paragraph you linked proves my point. Your anecdote proves my point, gasoline has a much higher octane rating than diesel, will combust poorly in a compression ignition engine, made even worse at low charge temperatures, wash down the walls, dilute the oil, and destroy the engine.

Comment: @user71659 This seems pointless but I'll give it one more try. Read the words on the page. Used to. Used to. Used to. Not a myth. They used to blend gasoline into winter diesel. They don't anymore. Used to, "at least into the 1990s" is what I wrote. Not a myth. Used to. Don't anymore. But they used to. Don't see how the first paragraph proves your myth theory, but that's OK if you want to believe that. I'm done.

Comment: Again, you're giving incorrect information. Blending gasoline into diesel damages engines, as I explained, it doesn't combust and washes the cylinder walls. Gasoline into diesel does not meet ASTM requirements, the correct blend is with kerosene. Some rednecks may have done so in Podunk and they damaged their engine. Even if they didn't OP is driving a modern direct-injection diesel, which has much tighter tolerances, lubricity requirements, and aftertreatment so any anecdotes of how they used to do it are not applicable at all.

Comment: @user71659 This series of comments was an exceptionally roundabout way to finally get to the *useful* point in your last comments. Claiming "myth" on a documented historical fact is not useful and is needlessly off-putting. I've made an addendum to my answer for the OP's consideration with due credit to you. You would do well to get to the salient point if you have any in future comments instead of trolling.

Comment: Don't put words in my mouth. I never changed my position on you your myth. I don't claim some idiot didn't mix gasoline with diesel in their own car, but official winterized diesel has always been a mix of kerosene. Simple mechanics, gasoline ignites poorly without a spark.